# typescript how to filter json by date range

Tags: typescript, momentjs, angular2-services

I have a json data as below. I am using angular2 typescript to filter this json based on the date range. I am using Moment to format the date string. I need to filter the searchvalue against all the properties of the class. I managed with other properties. I dont know how to filter the date range. Can anyone help how to do this?

Filter criteria:
import * as moment from 'moment';

```
export class FilterCriteria {
    public from: string;
    public to: string;
    public searchValue: string;
    constructor() {
        this.from =  moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY').toString();
        this.to =  moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY').toString();
    }
}
```

Search method:

```
return this.searchItems
          .map((item) =>
                items.filter(item => item.id === criteria.searchValue
                            || item.time === criteria.searchValue
                            || item.alertType.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(criteria.searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1
                            || item.source === criteria.searchValue
                            || item.relevantComms.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(criteria.searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1
                            || item.to.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(criteria.searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1
                            || item.from.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(criteria.searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1));
```

And json data:

```
[
    {
        "from": "Sender",
        "to": "Receiver",
        "source": "Email",
        "id": "861068CM",
        "date": "24/07/17"
    },
    {
        "from": "Sender",
        "to": "Receiver",
        "source": "Email",
        "id": "861068CM",
        "date": "12/07/17"
    },
    {
        "from": "Sender",
        "to": "Receiver",
        "source": "Email",
        "id": "861068CM",
        "date": "09/07/17"
    },
    {
        "from": "Sender",
        "to": "Receiver",
        "source": "Email",
        "id": "861068CM",
        "date": "02/02/17"
    },
]
```

Comment: What type is the item to and from properties? Are they dates or moment objects?

Comment: from and to are string properties. the filter has to be applied to date property in the json

Answer (score 0):

I would use moments [query methods](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) isBefore and isAfter methods to compare the dates. 
Change the type of the from and to properties in the FilterCriteria class to moment type:

```
export class FilterCriteria {
    public from: Moment;
    public to: Moment;
    public searchValue: string;
    constructor() {
        this.from = moment(new Date()); 
        this.to = moment(new Date());
    }
}
```

Then use them in the filter:

```
criteria.from.isBefore(item.date) && criteria.to.isAfter(item.date)
```